# link a module and sheet so that when you copy sheet into a new book the module comes along

Tags: vba, module

I have a macro that creates a bunch of sheets from sets of data that I provide. The macro then creates some checkboxes which a future user will be able to click. The checkboxes have an `.OnAction = "Module"` function which needs to run with the future users input.

I'd like to be able to copy this user input sheet into a new workbook so that I don't provide the user with the rest of the macros or sheets/raw data in this book that are required to make the user input sheet. However every time I copy the sheet into a new book and click the checkboxes it open the original sheet and runs the module via the original sheet.

So my question is: How do I link the module and sheet so that when I copy the sheet the module comes along?
I've also tried placing the module inside the sheet object but I can't figure out how to get the `.OnAction` function to call it

Comment: Put the click handler in the sheet's code module?  Sorry just saw you tried that: should work...

Comment: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/correcting-shape-assigned-macro-links-after-copying-worksheet-vba

Comment: Hmm that's really good for reassigning the macros but the code provided in there doesn't copy the macro's into the new book so the same thing happens

Comment: if the code is in the sheet module then it will move with the sheet.

Comment: Yes but I can't get the .OnAction function to work with a sheet module

Comment: Isn't that's what covered in the link I posted?  What happens when you try to link a checkbox with a method in the sheet module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help! All the answers helped in their own way but the thing I was missing was that when using the `On.Action` function with a sheet module, The sheet has a different name as to what you've renamed it to in the tabs

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

First some code to add a checkbox and assign an OnAction method:

```
Sub AddCheckbox()
    Dim sht As Worksheet, cbx
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OriginalSheet")
    Set cbx = sht.CheckBoxes.Add(113.25, 56.25, 133.5, 20.25)
    cbx.Name = "cbx_1"
    cbx.Caption = "Testing"
    cbx.OnAction = sht.CodeName & ".CheckBoxClicked"
End Sub
```

In the code module for the sheet with the checkbox:

```
Public Sub CheckBoxClicked()
    Dim c
    c = Application.Caller
    Debug.Print c, Me.Name, Me.Parent.Name
End Sub
```

Output on clicking the checkbox:

```
cbx_1         OriginalSheet Book1
```

Next copy this sheet to another Workbook and re-assign the checkbox handler:

```
Sub CopySheet()
    Dim sht As Worksheet, cb As CheckBox
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OriginalSheet")

    Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True '<< make sure this is set
    sht.Copy after:=Workbooks("Book2").Sheets(1)
    Set sht = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets(2)
    sht.Name = "CopiedSheet"
    For Each cb In sht.CheckBoxes
        cb.OnAction = "'" & sht.Parent.Name & "'!" & _
                      sht.CodeName & ".CheckBoxClicked"
    Next cb

End Sub
```

Output on clicking on the checkbox in the copied sheet:

```
cbx_1    CopiedSheet   Book2
```